# Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode

Tags: asp.net

I am using `MySql` and `SQLLITE` in my application. When Inserting data or updating the data using `SQLLITE` my `session` value returning `null` after query is processed. So in-order to overcome this I write as follows in `Web.Config`

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"></sessionState>
```

Every thing works fine but when coming to a certain page I am getting the error as

`Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.`

In remaining pages every thing works fine can any one tell why this happens

Comment: Sounds pretty obvious. The big question is why you think the change is needed from In-Proc to something else. It sounds like your SQLLITE db might be in the BIN directory causing the app to restart every time, but without more info, who can be sure.

Comment: `leppie` yeah I had my `SQLLITE` in my `Bin` directory

Comment: @User: Posted as answer with solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds pretty obvious. The big question is why you think the change is needed from In-Proc to something else. It sounds like your SQLLITE db might be in the BIN directory causing the app to restart every time, but without more info, who can be sure.

`User` has responded that it is indeed so.

**Solution:** Move the SQLLITE db to another directory.